# Can you add swiping ability with a Progressive Web App?

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have researched this question and I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know if you can add the ability to swipe on a smartphone with a Progressive Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Look up Scroll Snap to see how to get your swipe stop points at the right place.
Look up Flexbox display as well.